# Arrange list of files based off list of keywords and put in numeric order

Tags: text-processing

I have a list of keywords in `keywords.txt`

```
cat & mouse
dog
mouse
```

and a long list of image files in file `images.txt`

```
8284,cat-mouse.jpg001
8286,cat-mouse.jpg003
8285,cat-mouse.jpg002
50,mouse.jpg004
52,mouse.jpg003
1000,dog.jpg003
1003,dog.jpg002
1002,dog.jpg001
51,mouse.jpg002
53,mouse.jpg001
```

I need the image list to look like the following

```
8284,cat-mouse.jpg001
8285,cat-mouse.jpg002
8286,cat-mouse.jpg003
1000,dog.jpg001
1002,dog.jpg002
1003,dog.jpg003
50,mouse.jpg001
51,mouse.jpg002
52,mouse.jpg003
53,mouse.jpg004
```

The image number before `,` needs to be in the correct numeric order for each keyword as well as the jpgxyz value needs to start with 001 and so on however the keyword list takes priority which is why cat & mouse > dog > mouse. The keywords list also contain characters the image files do not such as `& ! ,` and the keywords can be similar for example another keyword may be `dog2` which should not be combined.

Comment: Why does `cat & mouse` match `cat-mouse`? Is there some transformation going on?

Comment: Yes that's the way our software added it. For example our file 'The world is large & beautiful.jpg' will convert to 'The-world-is-large-beautiful.jpg001' and the keyword for those files is 'The world is large & beautiful'

Comment: I think we'd have to know what transformations your software is doing, in order to find the correct lines to group & sort together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar assumptions as @Freddy on the transform.

```
OUTPUT=output.txt
IMAGES=images.txt
KEYS=keywords.txt

if [ -f $OUTPUT ]; then rm $OUTPUT; fi
while read KEY; do
    KEY=$(echo "$KEY" | sed -E -e 's/[)(&!,]/ /g ; s/ +/-/g')
    echo "key is ,$KEY."
    grep -Po "[0-9]+,$KEY\.jpg" $IMAGES | sort -k1 -n -t, | cat -n | while read  N F
    do
        echo $F$(printf "%03g" $N) | tee -a $OUTPUT
    done
    echo
done < $KEYS
```

yields

```
key is ,cat-mouse.
8284,cat-mouse.jpg001
8285,cat-mouse.jpg002
8286,cat-mouse.jpg003

key is ,dog.
1000,dog.jpg001
1002,dog.jpg002
1003,dog.jpg003

key is ,mouse.
50,mouse.jpg001
51,mouse.jpg002
52,mouse.jpg003
53,mouse.jpg004
500,mouse.jpg005
```

to STDOUT, but the empty lines and keys are not written to the output file

The final `sort -k1 -n -t,` sorts the output numerically on each key so you don't get

```
500,mouse.jpg001
50,mouse.jpg002
51,mouse.jpg003
52,mouse.jpg004
53,mouse.jpg005
```

**EDIT**

To run this you can copy /paste the code into a terminal which is open in the directory containing `images.txt` and `keywords.txt`. The output will be written to `output.txt`. Change these names as suits you.

Otherwise, copy it to a text file and save to the location your files are in; make it executable (`chmod +x whateverYouCalledIt`) and then you can access it from the command line by typing `./whateverYouCalledIt`

If you do the same as above but save to a directory in your $PATH then you can run it anywhere with `whateverYouCalledIt`

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779951/how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-without-using-sh-or-bash-commands)

Also `()` added to the list of characters to be replaced by `-`

Comment: The output is in alphabetical order not based off the keywords file order. For example if you change "dog" to "ant" (and file names in images.txt) even though the keyword is second it will be placed at the top of output.

Comment: This is what I said in the first line of the post... just delete the `| sort` as per the revised post

Answer (score 0):

With the following assumptions for the keywords transformations:

- replace `&`, `!` and `,` with an empty string
- replace space character with `-`
- replace multiple `-` with one `-`

You have to modify the `sed` substitutions accordingly.

```
#!/bin/bash

# read keywords linewise
while IFS= read -r keyword; do

        # replace '&', '!', ',' with empty string ''
        # replace ' ' with '-'
        # replace multiple '-' with one '-'
        kw=$(echo "$keyword" | sed 's/[&!,]//g; s/ /-/g; s/-\+/-/g')
        echo "keyword: \"$keyword\" -> \"$kw\""
        count=0

        # filter input file by keyword without jpg index and sort numeric
        while IFS= read -r line; do
                # write sorted lines with new jpg index
                printf '%s%.3d\n' "$line" $((++count)) >> images.txt.new
        done < <(grep -o '[0-9]\+,'"$kw"'\.jpg' images.txt | sort -n)

done < keywords.txt
```

Notes:

- The output of the new image list is appended to `images.txt.new`. You have to delete this file before the next run.
- Non-matching keywords / wrong keyword transformations will result in missing / wrong output.

Output (only to see the keyword transformations):

```
$ ./script.sh
keyword: "cat & mouse" -> "cat-mouse"
keyword: "dog" -> "dog"
keyword: "mouse" -> "mouse"
```

Comment: I don't think, that the image extension `jpgXYZ` should be changed. As I understood, it also should be used for sorting, but after the second field and the first field. That is: sort by field N2, then by field N1, then by field N3. It doesn't make sense to change filenames - how can we find these files after?

Comment: Whatever OP reasons they did request the change to the jpg suffix. Look at e.g `S3.mouse`.

Comment: This does show the correct keywords. I forgot about ignoring ( ) too.

Comment: Instead of two sed commands what if we use `'sed s/ +/-/g'`

Comment: @Prvt_Yadv Agreed, the `sed` by [bu5hman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521184/332764) has one less command and includes the `(` and `)`. @Teddy291 You can replace it with his version.

Answer (score 0):

I can add some comments, if you need.

**First approach - gawk only:**

```
#!/bin/bash

gawk -F'[,.]' '

FNR == NR {
    gsub(/[&!, )(]+/, "-")
    keyword_arr[i++] = $0   
}

FNR != NR {
    image_arr[$2][$1]
}

END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"

    for(i in keyword_arr) {
        keyword = keyword_arr[i]
        jpg_cnt = 0
        for(image_num in image_arr[keyword]) {
            printf("%d,%s.jpg%03d\n", image_num, keyword, ++jpg_cnt)
        }
    }
}' keywords.txt images.txt
```

**Second approach - usage an auxiliary directory containing files for each keyword:**

```
#!/bin/bash

aux_dir='auxiliary_dir'

mkdir -p "$aux_dir"

gawk -F'[.,]' -v aux_dir="$aux_dir" '{
    print $1","$2 > aux_dir"/"$2
}' images.txt


sed -r 's/[!&, )(]+/-/' keywords.txt | while read keyword;
do
     sort -n "${aux_dir}/${keyword}" | gawk '{printf("%s.jpg%03d\n", $0, NR) }' 
done

# The 'echo' is added for safety while testing.
# The auxiliary directory is no longer needed, so can be removed
echo rm -r "${aux_dir}"
```

**Output:**

```
8284,cat-mouse.jpg001
8285,cat-mouse.jpg002
8286,cat-mouse.jpg003
1000,dog.jpg001
1002,dog.jpg002
1003,dog.jpg003
50,mouse.jpg001
51,mouse.jpg002
52,mouse.jpg003
53,mouse.jpg004
```